# How do you search for a "$" using ag (silver-searcher)?

Tags: search

I'm trying to search for parameterized strings of the form "${foo}".

`ag "${"` and `ag "\${"` return nothing.  How do you escape the "$"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was answered on their [github page](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/issues/482#issuecomment-55115466):

> Since you're using double quotes, you're only escaping the dollar sign
>   from the shell. By the time ag sees it, it is an unescaped dollar sign
>   and therefore interpreted as end of line. Try single quotes or proper
>   escaping:
>
> `$ ag '\$timeout'`
>
> `$ ag "\\\$timeout"`
>
> The reason grep is not affected, is because it uses basic regular
>   expressions by default. With -E it behaves the same.